# Do I need to recompress a thumb created from compressed image?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I want all my images to compressed to quality of 80.
Let's say user upload JPG image, I set the compression level to 80 and save.
Now after some time I create thumbnail from that image, do I need to recompress that thumbnail to 80?

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to compress the original and then create the thumbnail?  Is there a problem with the thumbnail?

Comment: @gariepy there is no problem, just asking if a thumbnail image of image with quality of 80, is consider to be 80 quality or 100

Comment: No, I would not.  When you compress the original, you lose information, and then when you create a thumbnail, you lose a lot more information.  Thumbnails are tiny, though, so I don't see the benefit in compressing the thumbnail even further.

Comment: When you compress, the quality is gone permanently. Like @gariepy said,  when you compress a thumb, you might save, say, 25%, but in actual bytes (the things that have actual costs associated with them—as opposed to ratios), you're likely only saving a few KB.